# How to solve polynomial Differential Equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was exploring polynomials of differential equations and I need some help. I have two equations below please help me solve either of them, I can't find a substitution that works:

$1.$ $Ax+By+C\dfrac{dy}{dx}+D=0$

$2.$ $Ax^2+Bx+Cy^2+Dy+Exy+Fx\dfrac{dy}{dx}+Gy\dfrac{dy}{dx}+H\dfrac{dy}{dx}+I\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2+K=0$

For the first I tried:

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{-Ax-By-D}{C}$

Then I made the substitution $y=vx$ , $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=v+x\dfrac{dv}{dx}$

To get:

$v+x\dfrac{dv}{dx}=\dfrac{-Ax-Bvx-D}{C}$

Subtracting $v$ I received:

$x\dfrac{dv}{dx}=\dfrac{-Ax-Bvx-D}{C}-v$

and still not really anywhere...

I am at a loss to tackle the second form.

Comment: If there are no elementary solutions then that will also be fine as an answer. Please give a proof or explanation why there cannot be elementary solutions. (If it can be solved by extending beyond algebraic operations to tetration etc... that would be nice to look at)

Comment: I give a suggestion. Why don't you first solve DFQ 1  with a set of values for A,B and C. Do your suggested substitution (which makes sense!) and see how the numbers play out.

Comment: One can but wonder at your optimism that the second equation will be solvable in explicit form! The first one, on the other hand, is a standard non-homogeneous linear equation, and any textbook on ODE will explain how to solve it.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas, note that TEX is the requirement of typing the equations in SE.

Comment: the second equation is a quadratic in $\frac{dy}{dx}$ with the coefficients function of $x$ and $y.$  so you have $\frac{dy}{dx} = rhs(x, y).$ you can now see if the rhs is contnuous which guarantees existence and if lipshitz, then you also have uniqueness.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1 is just a linear ODE.
The homogeneous solution comes from $By+Cy'=0$, which gives $y_o = c_o e^{-B/C}x$.

The heterogeneous solution can be solved by guessing a solution of the form $y_o+\alpha x + \beta$, which gives a final solution of $y = c_0e^{-B/C}x-\frac{A}{B}x+\frac{AC-BD}{B^2}$.

Comment: Both are ODEs: you mean it is a **linear** ODE.